# Generic type functions in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, datatypes, functions

Consider the following function

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SafeDivide
(
    @a numeric,
    @b numeric
)
RETURNS numeric
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE
               WHEN @b = 0
                   THEN 0
               ELSE @a / @b
           END;
END;
```

Here type `numeric` was used but this code would be useful for any numeric types with any precision.

Is there a way to define and use such function?

I tried `sql_variant` type but it complains

```
Operand data type sql_variant is invalid for divide operator
```

Comment: Not in the language.  Many functions just convert the arguments to ‘float’ and make the caller convert back.

Comment: @JoeObbish I'm looking for a type with maximum precision so any numeric type can be casted to it without losing precision

Answer (score 1):

The error says what to do, that sql_variant type does not accept to operate the divide function.

I would suggest to use CONVERT/CAST to a specific data type, depending on your usage.
Below I will use float:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dbo.SafeDivide
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SafeDivide
(
    @a sql_variant,
    @b sql_variant
)
RETURNS sql_variant
AS
BEGIN
     RETURN CASE
               WHEN @b = 0
                   THEN 0.00
               ELSE Convert(float, @a) / Convert(float, @b) 
           END;
END
GO
/*
select dbo.SafeDivide(4,4.4622434)
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is practical. Consider the following example:

```
DECLARE @big_value_for_u NUMERIC(38,0) = 99999999999999999999999999999999999999,
@small_value NUMERIC(38, 38) = 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000001;
```

What data type would you want the following expression to have?

```
SELECT @big_value_for_u / @small_value
```

`NUMERIC` has a max precision of 38 and `FLOAT` only has eight bytes. There must be some loss of precision with a numeric data type. Databases in general expect you to define your data type ahead of time. If you're saving the result of that division to a column or variable then you'll need to do that.

I suppose that you could convert everything to strings, roll your own division method, and give the output as a string. But what would you do with the result then?

Comment: Well, if you can write in plain SQL `SELECT @big_value_for_u / @small_value`, so I would like my helper function to work exactly the same way as division operator

Comment: @mnaoumov You can't: Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type numeric.